# enabling copy/ paste on ubuntu-server 18.04.4

Tags: server, clipboard, xclip

How can I use xclip to create a shared clipboard experience?
I require to have a shared clipboard with a `iDRAC Dell` server running `ubuntu-server 18.04.4`. The install is a minimal install without cursor. I tried using `xclip` but seems like I'm unable to copy the contents of a file into clipboard. I'm getting the following error

```
Cannot open display (null)
```

I would also like to have some background information on the explanation of error. End goal is to have a shared clipboard. Passing a display value also didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Clipboard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard) is an X protocol concept. Since there is no X server running, you get an error message.
Passing a display value is vain, for there is actually none. This is the same for any graphical utility
on a headless machine.

Nothing, however, prevents you from dumping contents into a file and retrieving contents from it as
a clipboard would do. If going this route, an appropriate set of bash aliases or functions would make the process smoother.
Otherwise, check out [How to get clipboard support on a Linux server without X11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/216347) and the links therein for alternatives.